# org.apache.log4j.Logger class not found in integration test with arquillian

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian

I have the following problem:

Environment:

1. Weblogic 12.1.3
2. MySQL
3. Gradle
4. Log4j

Sharedlib:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 josediaz  staff     0B Jan 19 17:06 Readme.txt
drwxrwxrwx   2 josediaz  staff    68B Mar 31 20:48 build
-rwxr-xr-x   1 josediaz  staff   1.1K Jun 30 01:05 build.gradle
drwxrwxrwx   9 josediaz  staff   306B Jul  1 01:31 dao-ifz.jar
drwxrwxrwx  10 josediaz  staff   340B Jul  1 01:31 dao-imp.jar
drwxrwxrwx   5 josediaz  staff   170B Mar 31 20:48 dependencias
drwxrwxrwx   9 josediaz  staff   306B Jul  1 01:31 model.jar
drwxrwxrwx   9 josediaz  staff   306B Jul  1 01:31 service-ifz.jar
drwxrwxrwx   9 josediaz  staff   306B Jul  1 01:31 service-imp.jar
-rwxr-xr-x   1 josediaz  staff   578B Apr 27 23:02 settings.gradle
drwxrwxrwx  11 josediaz  staff   374B Jul  1 01:31 slb.ear
drwxr-xr-x  11 josediaz  staff   374B Jul  1 01:31 test.jar
```

I have a `JPAPersonDAO` in my dao-imp of my sharedlib and I am using log4j for do logging:

```
@Stateless
public class JPAPersonDAO implements PersonDAO {



    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JPAPersonDAO.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistence-unit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Person> findPersons(int startPosition, int maxResults, String sortFields, String sortDirections) {

        LOG.warn("warn");
        LOG.info("info");
        LOG.trace("trace");
        LOG.debug("debug");
        LOG.error("error");
        LOG.fatal("fatal");



        return entityManager
                .createNativeQuery("select * from person order by name limit " + startPosition + "," + maxResults,
                        Person.class)
                .getResultList();

    }
```

This is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

log4j.debug=true

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.File=/Users/josediaz/Projects/logs/logging_sharedlib.log
log4j.appender.file.Append = false
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize = 20000Kb
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex = 5
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p %c %x - %m%n


log4j.category.com.theserverlabs.blog.wls=DEBUG
```

When I deployed my sharedlib and other EAR use it, the log is generated without problems.

**The problem**

I add a test project with a integration test based in arquillian.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class NativeSqlTest {


    @Inject
    PersonDAO dao;

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addClasses(PersonDAO.class, JPAPersonDAO.class, Person.class, Profiled.class,
                        ProfilingInterceptor.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource("test-beans.xml", "beans.xml")
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
    }

    /**
     * In the test, we're just going to invoke the only available operation in
     * the +EmployeeBean+ and assert a few details to confirm that the native
     * query was successfully executed.
     */
    @Test
    public void testNativeSql() {



        int result = dao.countPersons();
        assertTrue(result > 0);
    }
}
```

Whether I execute this test from my IDE or call `gradle clean build` from terminal, I get the following error:

> org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Deployment Failed on server: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering if adding `Logger.class` in your `@Deployment` can solve the problem ? Because your class `JPAPersonDAO` uses `Logger.class`, but the logger isn't shipped in your deployment.

Comment: I add this to my code:   return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "testSharedlib.war")
    .addClasses(PersonDAO.class, JPAPersonDAO.class, Person.class, Profiled.class,
      ProfilingInterceptor.class, Logger.class) and the error change to Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Category

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [Mincong Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4381330/mincong-huang) your suggestion was fundamental. I added this to my deployment  .addPackages(true, "org.apache.log4j") and test passed.

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "testSharedlib.war")
            .addClasses(PersonDAO.class, JPAPersonDAO.class, Person.class, Profiled.class,
                    ProfilingInterceptor.class)
             .addPackages(true, "org.apache.log4j")
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsResource("log4j.xml")             
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-beans.xml", "beans.xml");

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Other option would be to use maven resolver and pull in this dependency as a jar. Then you would simply add it as library to the final `.war` file.